# Django : Swapping Elements in a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a many to many relationship setup on two models the standard way.

```
class UserSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, through='ItemUserSet')

class ItemUserSet(models.Model):
    set = models.ForeignKey(UserSet)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

So i basically have a number of items and any number of users can create sets of items for their personal list.

I want to allow a user to swap an item on his list with another one and this action also performs the swap on the list of any other users who happen to have the item which one user swapped.

```
orig_item = Item.objects.get(uuid=orig_uuid)
repl_item = Item.objects.get(uuid=repl_uuid)
board_uuid = request.GET['board'] or None

board = UserSet.objects.filter(uuid=board_uuid) 
ius = ItemUserSet.objects.filter(item__uuid=orig_uuid)

for u_set in board:
    u_set.items_set.remove(orig_item)
    u_set.items_set.add(repl_item)
    c['msg']='OK'
for sets in ItemUserSet:
    sets.item = repl_item.pk
    sets.save()
```

but this doesnt work. i get this error.

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

basically when one user selects two items to be swapped, if that item is there in any users board, the swap should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i figured out what i was doing wrong.

Apparently, in cases like this, you need to do any manipulation to the manytomany relationship  itself through the "through" model. (hence maybe the name?)
I guess thats what the django docs were trying to say about this.. :/

so i sorted it out by:

```
for s in ius:
    s.item = repl_item
    s.save()
```

it works pretty fine. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will be the right answer for you, but it seems like you are trying to remove from manager object and not item itself.

I don't have the time to test this out, but if you maybe try putting .all() to the end of

> board = UserSet.objects.filter(uuid=board_uuid)

which will actually pull out items and not just return manager.
I had similar problem some time ago in the template and it helped me.

Comment: thanks but that did not work. I found a workaround though.. see my answer.

Comment: `.filter` and `.all` both return `QuerySet`s, so `.all` is unnecessary here.